# Fieldset onclick getting radio button clicked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onclick, fieldset

I have a fieldset in my HTML which basically represents 5 star rating system like following:

```
<fieldset class="rating" id="ratingSystem">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```

And I've defined an onclick event which defines when user clicks on some of the star ratings (radio buttons) then I'd simply for testing purposes display the clicked value, but I always get double values displayed instead of the displayed one...

For instance if I clicked on 5 I get displayed  in console:

```
undefined  
5
```

Second time I click on 4 I get values:

```
5
4
```

The code I use for it is:

```
$('#ratingSystem').click(function () {
        console.log($('input[name=rating]:checked').val());
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit, these are the CSS classes that I use to turn the radio buttons into stars so that it looks like star rating system:

```
fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

Could any of these classes be the source of the issue?

Comment: Can you provide more information when I run the code provided in jsfiddle I get no issues. https://jsfiddle.net/fq56bxzz/

Comment: Are you sure don't have another set of `input[name=rating]` somewhere else, maybe hidden, on the page ?

Comment: @DominicValenciana Yes , on top of this HTML I'm using CSS classes to turn these radio buttons into stars... I'll update my question in a sec to show u

Comment: @Piou 100% certain, this is the only input that has class rating

Comment: @User987 Perfect, It may be that css is some how blocking elements. I've had this issue a few times my self.

Comment: @DominicValenciana Is any of these causing the issue ?

Comment: @User987 I added the css and I am getting the issue now. I'll have an answer helping you out in a moment :)

Comment: I think the pseudo elements are messing around

Comment: @Piou, Dominic amazing you guys, thanks I got the clue now what causes the issue, i've fixed it. You guys saved me from a lot of time spent looking into the wrong thing, thanks !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may attaching another event to the `checkbox`'s somewhere else but you could check the working snippet below based on your OP code shows that the `console.log` fire just one time on click.

I suggest to attach the click to the input directly the get the current checked value using just :

```
$(this).val();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#ratingSystem input').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```css
fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
  float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="rating" id="ratingSystem">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to attach your event to each `input` elements:

```js
$('#ratingSystem input').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="rating" id="ratingSystem">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```